# useSWR error is undefined after promise rejection - upgrade to v2

Tags: typescript, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library, swr

I have a unit test for useSWR that has started failing after my upgrade to v2.2.0, seeming because the `error` returned by useSwr is undefined even when the fetcher returns a rejected promise.

Here's the prod code:

```
import * as api from "@/lib/api-client/apiClient";

const { data, error } = useSWR<UserData | undefined>(
    state.user.id,
    api.getUserData,
  );

console.log(error);
```

In the test, I am mocking the apiClient to alway return a rejected promise from the `getUserData` fetcher function:

```
jest.mock("@/lib/api-client/apiClient", () => ({
  getUserData: jest.fn(),
}));
const mockApi = api as jest.Mocked<typeof api>;

it("handles error", async () => {
  const rejectedPromise = Promise.reject(500);
  mockApi.getUserData.mockReturnValue(rejectedPromise);

  const result = await setupHook(currentUser);

  await act(() => {
    return rejectedPromise.catch(() => {});
  });

  // rest of test behavior
});
```

You don't need to worry about the `setupHook` because this test file has a dozen other tests using the same setup that are working properly. Same with the mocking - it's the same as the other tests use, that's not the problem.

This test was working until I upgraded from v1 to v2. Now, the error never console-logs as anything other than `undefined`. Before v2, it would log as `500` as expected (and the rest of the code would handle the error appropriately).

Why is the `error` to no longer registering the rejected promise?